# JavaScript Regex Expression needed for split method

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove characters after numbers and needs to include .pdf extension.

I cannot use index since the file name varies on dates and names.

ex: My File Name : Mar 1316 and A - sec.pdf

required output file name: Mar1316.pdf

can anyone help with the regex and split method?

Comment: Are you using node?

Comment: No, I'  using javacript

Comment: String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can be only one sequence of numbers or you want until the last sequence  you can use this regex: `(.*[1-9]+)`

- `.*`: any character any number of time
- `[1-9]+`: 1 number or more

```js
const str = "Mar 1316 and A - sec.pdf";
const match = /.*[1-9]+/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    // will equal 'Mar 1316.pdf'
    const newStr = str.slice(0, match[0].length) + '.pdf';
}
```

Comment: String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

var str = name;
newName = str;                                                                                                              This is the code I've can you let me know how to add above logic in here? name is my original file name

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with JS regex, simply because you need both lookbehind and lookahead in the same regex, which I believe you cannot do.

```
/\s+|(?<=\d).*(?=\.)/
```